# Trouble adding multiple images to an e-mail

Tags: excel, vba, email, hyperlink

I have an e-mail that is generated through Excel with VBA. This e-mail includes two embedded pictures in the body of the e-mail along with the separate hyperlinks to the videos they refer to. The problem is that it isn't recognizing the second picture and just embedding the same picture twice, however the hyperlinks are correct. Below is a sample of my code:

```
Private Sub SubmitBtn_Click()
Dim Source As Range
Dim Dest As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim MemNme As String, Email As String, UsrName As String, domainID As String, pic As String, pic2 As String
Dim Hlink As String, Hlink2 As String
State = Screener.StateBox
 If State = "California" Then
        If Screener.MktPlcBox = True Then
            pic = "websitewithpicture1"
            Hlink = "videolink"
            count = 1
        End If
        If Screener.SubsidyBox = True Then
            pic2 = "websitewithpicture2"
            Hlink2 = "videolink"
            count = 2
        End If
With OutMail
            .To = Email
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Helpful Video"
            .HTMLBody = "Dear " & MemNme & ",<br><br>" _
            & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Thank you for speaking with me today about your plan. You have a lot of choices, " _
            & " and <b>we appreciate you choosing company</b>. Helping you understand your plan is important to us and I thought this video would be valuable to you.<br><br>" _
            & vbNewLine & "<center><a href=" & Hlink & "<img src=cid:" & Replace(pic, " ", " ", "520") & " height =250 width=400></a>" _
            & "<a href=" & Hlink2 & "<img src=cid:" & Replace(pic2, " ", " ", "420") & " height =250 width=400></a></center><br>" _
            & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "You can always get additional information at <b>website.com</b> or by calling the number on the back of your card.<br><br>" _
            & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Thank you,<br>" _


 & vbNewLine & UsrName 

        .Attachments.Add pic, olByValue, 0
        .Attachments.Add pic2, olByValue, 0 <--------It doesn't "See" this pic???
'            MsgBox "Press ok to create your e-mail"
        .Display  'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using a more differentiated name?

Comment: Your Replace calls don't make sense. What is `Replace(pic, " ", " ", "520")` supposed to do?

Comment: Is it possible that `Screener.SubsidyBox = False` ?

Comment: You should make a more generic body with special tags to replace depending on your control values in the `Screener`. The email attachments should also act differently according these control values.

Comment: @Andre451, Frankly, I don't quite understand the Replace calls either, but if they aren't there, it doesn't work?

Comment: @LiamH - I checked the Screener and it is True

Comment: I agree it doesn't make sense but just so you know your replace appears to be replacing spaces with spaces starting from the 520th character of you `pic` string.

Comment: @LiamH I understand that, but, again, If i take it out, the pic doesn't show up at all..strange